# How to split phone number and name from the text string using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
tenant_details = "Tasha Robinson (123) 4178-6875"
name = re.search("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)",tenant_details)
print(name)
```

Required solution:

```
Name: Tasha Robinson
Phone No: (123) 4178-6875
```

The name can be full name or first name and phone number can be in any format like `+1 854 545454` ..

Comment: You should specify more the very broad requirement *... phone number can be in any format ...*

Comment: @AndrejKesely Requirement is just split name and phone number. You can take phone number (\d+) only digits no need of + or ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that phone number consists only from characters `+()\d-` and spaces. Then you can use:

```py
import re

tenant_details = "Tasha Robinson (123) 4178-6875"

name, phone = re.match(r"(.*?)\s([)(+\d -]+)$", tenant_details).groups()
print(f"{name=}")
print(f"{phone=}")
```

Prints:

```
name='Tasha Robinson'
phone='(123) 4178-6875'
```